# It have something wrong in my code by using Split in Winform

Tags: c#, winforms

I have this code:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string s="hello\amynameis\alam";
    string[] arr = s.Split('\a');
    foreach (string str in arr)
    {
        textBox1.Text = str + "\n";
    }
}
```

I want output to be as :

```
hello  
mynameis  
lam
```

But it only shows "lam" in the textBox1. I don't know why.

Answer (score 7):

Your error is originated inside the for loop, where you set the text property of the textbox to the current item. Of course this ends with your textbox showing only the last item of the array.

You can use [string.Join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0(v=vs.110).aspx) to build a multiline string, but remember to set the [Multiline](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12w624ff(v=vs.110).aspx) property of the TextBox to true to allow your textbox to show multiple lines

```
string s="hello\amynameis\alam";
string[] arr = s.Split('\a');
//textBox1.Text = string.Join("\r\n", arr);
textBox1.Text = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, arr);
```

You can even trim a line from your code with a simple replace

```
t.Text = s.Replace("\a", Environment.NewLine);
```

Notice also that the `\n` character alone is NOT enough to make a newline in a textbox. You need to add also the `\r` or better [Environment.NewLine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thank you so much, but it only connect string together . Output like that: hellomynameislam but it not accept "\n" character. Please help me!!

Comment: yess! I saw your update. It's successful. Thank you so much